# Passing to v-model a composed value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

I'm using Quasar v.2 with VueJs 3.
I'm using the [q-select](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select) component in order to switch dynamically the language. Here's my code:

```
    <template>
         <q-select v-model="$i18n.locale" :options="langs">
         </q-select>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
        export default defineComponent({
          name: 'LanguageSwitch',
          setup() {
             const langs = ['en', 'jp']
             return {langs}
          }
    
    </script>
```

What I want to do now is to keep displaying "en" and "jp", and to concatenate them with another word (to form, for example "en-US") in the moment I pass them to the i18n.locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update `langs` to include the desired values and labels:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const langs = [
      { value: 'en-US', label: 'en' },
      { value: 'jp-JP', label: 'jp' },
    ]
    return { langs }
  }
}
```

Then set `<q-select>.optionValue` to `"value"` so it uses the item's `value` property as the option value, and `<q-select>.optionLabel` to `"label"` to use the item's `label` property as the label:

```html
<q-select v-model="$i18n.locale" :options="langs"
  option-value="value"
  option-label="label">
</q-select>
```

Comment: You forgot to add "emit-value" (When emit-value is used, the model becomes the determined value from the specified selected option. Default is to emit the whole option. It makes sense to use it only when the options are of Object form.)

Only one other question: now it displays the value and not the label, so it displays: "en-US" instead of only "en". Is there a way to fix this? At the moment I'm using "map-options", but I read that there is a performance penalty when using it